# excel 2016 return cell according to current month

Tags: excel

can anyone help me with an excel 2016 formula.

I have values in A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, A11, A12

I want to return those values into A13 depending on the current month.

e.g. if current month is JAN then return value in A1 into A13, if current month is MAY then return A5 into A13.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the `INDEX` function, in `A13`

`=INDEX(A1:A12,MONTH(TODAY()),1)`

[image]

Adding for A4:L4 range,

[image]

Comment: Hi, that works great in columns, however when I try to use in rows it doesnt work.

Comment: e.g. =INDEX(A4:L4,MONTH(TODAY()),1)

Comment: @Ollie invert the '1' and 'month(today()).. The syntax for index function is ,  index(range,row number,column number)

Comment: Sorry to be an idiot about this, but can you show example like you did before. But instead of A1,A2,A3 ect

Comment: A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1 returning in M!

Comment: @Ollie Updated the answer. Formula is `=INDEX(A4:L4,1,MONTH(TODAY()))`

Comment: Thanks @Ollie. Please upvote and mark my answer as correct if you found this useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel 2016 but please try:

```
=OFFSET(A1,MONTH(TODAY())-1,)
```